# Object extraction after Canny

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have found out edges  by using canny edge algorithm in OpenCV Java. I need to extract the spinal cord from this image.

Can you please suggest the next steps to extract the spinal cord only from this image?

[image]

This is the original image:

[image]

Comment: Please add also the original image. From the Canny'ed image is almost impossible to achieve what you want.

Comment: hi @Miki I have uploaded the original image but it's not being shown..

Comment: I've edited the image into the question. I should warn you that since you have already marked this question as answered, it's very unlikely that someone else will answer this.

Comment: Sorry @Miki I didn't know that that sign meant answered. Is it better to post the question again or it's okay now as i removed the answered mark? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's ok now. Just remember to give credits to useful answers, even if they don't fully answer your question, with upvotes. Once you find an answer that really helps you, put also the mark

Answer (score 1):

to extract a specific object from an image you have to find the contours in the canny image first. You can use `findContours()` to get all contours in the image. This link shows a tutorial on how to do this: http://bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/ This tutorial shows a C++ code but java opencv is just an api mapping C++ functions to java.

Next step is to do some calculations about the width and hight ratios of the contours and then you can extract them from your image.

This is not an easy task to do. Research hard to figure out some stuff related to ratios of width and height of the spine.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the fast response. I will try the tutorial. In the meantime, could you please share your code in my email address here? tanvir.dpmiracle[at][gmail][dot][com]    btw, is your code in c++?

Comment: Sorry, I should have told before that I need to extract the "spinal cord" only. Not the whole spine. I'm using this code to find the contours: `List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();         Imgproc.findContours(destination, contours, new Mat(), 
           Imgproc.RETR_TREE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);` but the image is quite distorted after applything this method

Comment: you should take a clone of the image and apply findContours() on it, you then have to loop through contours to find the right one. I will give you more guideline as soon as i finish my work.

Comment: ok, thanks. By the mean time, I will try to provide the canny edged image

Comment: Number of found contours: 12957, Giving the code in my next comment

Comment: `List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();Mat cloned = source.clone();
         int areaThreshold = 10;
         Imgproc.findContours(cloned, contours, new Mat(),Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        System.out.println("Total contours: "+contours.size());
        for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++){
   MatOfPoint currentContour = contours.get(i);
   double currentArea = Imgproc.contourArea(currentContour);   
   if(currentArea > areaThreshold){
    System.out.println("Points: " +contours.get(i).size().height+ " Area: "+currentArea);
    } }`

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, there are so many variables here. However, if all images of spine are of the same size, you can do matching, Opencv has function to do template matching:
[matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html)

I would also consider using Hough transform to detect rectangles/squares since the Spine is clearly composed of several rectangles [Hough](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Samer. I guess the spines are all same sizes but the curved edges might have different angles due to the bending of the neck. Well, i think it's a great idea. I will definitely try this out and let you know :)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I meant spinal cord.. the plain rope like structure beside the spine.